# SAP Crystal Reports Runtime Engine for .Net Framework 4

Tags: .net, windows, crystal-reports

I have a system developed at C# and have some reports made by crystal reports. I installed the system in a computer with Windows 7 64 bits and everything works fine but when I try to install the SAP Crystal Reports Runtime Engine for .Net Framework 4 I got this message "This software package can only be installed on systems that has installed .Net Framework 2.0 or higher".

The computer has installed Microsoft .Net Framework 4 Client Profile and Microsoft .Net Framework 4 Extended.

Answer (score 0):

Update your OS, using  windows update setting or install the current .net Framework from [dotnet-framework-runtime](https://www.microsoft.com/net/download/dotnet-framework-runtime)